# What am I doing wrong? CURL PHP Cookies

Tags: php, cookies, curl

I'm using curl to login to a website, It manages to log me in and display the page back saying "Thanks for logging in Jack Brown" and I can see the member area.

However a cookie file is not being created on my server "/tmp/cookie.txt"

Since I have logged in, I then want to use curl again to retrieve data from the members area but when running this part of the page I just get the "Please login to continue".

The first bit of code is for logging in (this logs me in okay but don't create a cookie file):

```
<?php

$email    = 'email@here.com';
$password = 'passwordhere';
$rememberMe = '';
$redirect = '';
// initial login page which redirects to correct sign in page, sets some cookies
$URL = 'https://www.website.co.uk/home';
$coookie = tempnam ("/tmp", "CURLCOOKIE");

$ch  = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $URL);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $cookie);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $cookie);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; U; Linux x86_64; en-US; rv:1.9.2.13) Gecko/20101206 Ubuntu/10.10 (maverick) Firefox/3.6.13');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);        
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);

$page = curl_exec($ch);


$URL2 = "login url is normally here"; // this is our post url

$postdata = "_58_login=".$email."&_58_password=".$password."&_58_rememberMe=".$rememberMe."&_58_redirect=".$redirect; 

$post = substr($post, 0, -1);

// set additional curl options using our previous options
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $URL2);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, $URL);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postdata);

$page = curl_exec($ch); // make request

// try to find the actual login form
if (!preg_match('/Thanks for loggin in/is', $page, $form)) {
    die('Erorr: Could not login!');
}
var_dump($page); // should be logged in

// END OF LOGIN
```

This next bit of  code is in the same document, and is used to open another page in the members area which I can pull content from however this page just returns saying that i'm not logged in:

```
$URLOPEN = 'http://www.website.co.uk/membersareacontent';
$URL5 = 'http://www.website.co.uk/thanksforlogginin';


curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $URLOPEN);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, $URL5);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $cookie);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $cookie);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; U; Linux x86_64; en-US; rv:1.9.2.13) Gecko/20101206 Ubuntu/10.10 (maverick) Firefox/3.6.13');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);        
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);

$page2 = curl_exec($ch);
var_dump($page2); // should be show members content
```

Comment: Add `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER, TRUE);` and update your post with latest changes about what the problem is now. I see in comments to answers that you've made it further, than is described here, but still need help

Answer (score 0):

Edit: sbeliv01 has point that cookie is misspelled
If not try to add this at top of your code to display if there is any error:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set("display_errors",1);
```

And this code to check if file is available to write, and make sure cookie file is writeable:

```
// change $cookie_file_path to yours
$fp = fopen($cookie_file_path,'wb') or die("can't open cookie file");
fclose($fp);
```

Also i noticed you have not set your cookie options here:

```
// set additional curl options using our previous options
$ch  = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $URL2);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, $URL);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postdata);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $cookie);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $cookie);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);        
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
```

Comment: Added both lots of code and corrected cookie name however still in the same situation, no error codes regarding the cookie being writeable.

Comment: I noticed you dont have CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR option when request being sent with post.

Comment: I have added these in, no difference made still :( Thanks for your help so far though!

Comment: is cookie file being created now or not? if not can u try to create manually a cookie file and chmod 777 then give full path to ur variable $cookie = '/full/path/to/cookie.txt'

Comment: cookie file is now being created,

Comment: have it added any cookie information for site login in cookie file?

Comment: do you have permission to login to that site? if yes let me know site link and i will test for you.

Comment: add RETURNTRANSFER and FOLLOWLOCATION for post call, check edited code above. I cant help you further without knowing site URL.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps because the variable name has an extra `o` when declared at the top then the one you're using in your cURL later on:

```
$coookie = tempnam ("/tmp", "CURLCOOKIE"); // Notice coookie with the extra o

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $cookie); // Spelled with only two o's here
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $cookie);  // Spelled with only two o's here
```

Comment: Thanks, i have changed that but still having the same problem.